# Error with WSO2 API Manager OAuth Authentication

Tags: oauth, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I installed the latest WS02 API Manager, 1.6.0.  I followed the directions and just did the plain install, nothing special.  When I create an API, publish it, subscribe to it, create an Access Token, and try to access it, I am seeing the following error (I replaced the access key, but it is displaying):

```
[2014-02-03 13:25:47,850] ERROR - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Access failure for API: /weather, version: 1 with key: access_key
```

It seems that the API and access key are not getting connected.  Is there something else that I have to do to make that happen?  I am not using a separate database for the Key Manager, just whatever comes with the install which is a memory DB I assume.  I have tried this from Advanced Rest Client in Chrome.  I'm guessing something's just not configured correctly, but I don't see any errors in the start-up.  I just see a few warnings along these lines:

```
[2014-02-03 13:25:01,262]  WARN - DefaultSchemaGenerator We don't support method overloading. Ignoring [validateAudience Restriction]
```

Here is the full stack trace for the error:

```
[2014-02-03 13:25:47,850] ERROR - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Access failure for API: /weather, version: 1 with key: access_key
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.jav
a:139)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHand
ler.java:92)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:285)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:76)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:63)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:220)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:336
)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:168)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: How did you execute your API? can you provide your request URL?

Comment: Did you publish the service? Did you subscribe on the service? Did you generate a access-token? Did you sent the access-token in the Soap header (Authentication: bearer xxx..access-token..xxx?

Comment: What's the response you got this request? It seems you are providing the Authorization header correctly, but the token you are using is invalid/expired. See the link on subscribing to an API and the Applications concept. You generate a token for an application not for an API. An Application is a (logical) collection of APIs. http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Subscribing+to+APIs

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  This is the request URL that I used: http://localhost:8280/weather/1.  I did publish the service, subscribe to it, generate an access token and send the access token in the header.  If I look under subscriptions in the API Store, the weather API is there for the access token that I'm using.  The response:  <ams:fault>
<ams:code>900906</ams:code>
<ams:message>No matching resource found in the API for the given request</ams:message>
<ams:description>Access failure for API: /weather, version: 1 with key: access_token</ams:description>
 </ams:fault>

Comment: I figured it out.  Somewhere along the way I had checked a radio box in Advanced Rest Client for "delete" instead of "get".  I didn't even think to check it originally because I assumed it was still on "get".  Thank you for all of your help.  I wanted to come post my answer in case anyone else runs into a similar problem.  Just missed one small but very important detail.